# How to fix "cannot change android hint colour with text input edit text"

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I can't change my android hint colour with the "android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText".
How i fix this ?

I've tried change my styles.xml but it doesn't work and add some colour with colours.xml, but it doesn't work too.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/customtextinput">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:theme="@style/customtextinput2"
            android:hint="Nama Lengkap"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
            android:backgroundTint="#42adf4"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I expect the output of my xml project is blue, the hint colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i have used this code in my project and it's working .I hope it will work for you too .

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/fNameTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtSignUp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
    android:textColorHint="@color/p2_text_color_dark_blue" <!--hint color-->
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Here is hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And in your style copy this

```
 <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp20</item>
</style>
```

Comment: the "android:textColourHint" become red when i use your code, any solution ?, i think i must copy the colour xml too not only the style, am i right ?

Comment: Yes you have to apply your color in android:textColourHint attribute.